# qtranslate arabic shortcode?

Tags: multi-language, troubleshooting

I used qTranslate in my site. Four language selections.

```
English
Russian
Turkish
Arabic
```

But Arabic does not work. I tried this url: `site.com/ar` but it still does not work. Shows an error like the following:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at
> /home/useruser/public_html/www.site.com/blog/wp-content/themes/tema/index.php:1)
> in
> /home/useruser/public_html/www.site.com/blog/wp-content/themes/tema/header.php
> on line 1

Answer (score 2):

Not the first line but the last line could be it.

Please check if you have a space after the last `?>` sign of your `header.php` file. Its better suggested that you just remove the last `?>` sign as well. So there wont be any headers already sent error generated.

And this sort of error usually occurs when you include a file before a header() or cookie() or session function call.

Answer (score 0):

...I can't see your site  but anyway this problem occurs when you have BLANK spaces in the code. Make sure there is no space at the very top (line 1) of the php file.